# Different source files in different build types in gradle builds?

Tags: java, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Now that Android Studio uses Gradle Build System: Is it possible to have different source files or compiler switches for debug and release build.

In fact in my project there are some differences - e.g. I want to have different endpoint urls or bugreport urls when my application is built in debug mode.

As far as I know, in plain Java it's not possible to have compiler switches just like

```
#if DEBUG
   // do something when in debug build
#else
   // do something when not in debug build
#endif
```

in C#.

Does Gradle or Android Studio itself provide me the possibility to compile different code dependent in the build type? And how to do this?

Two examples:

```
@ReportsCrashes(formKey = "", formUri = "http://mydebugcrashreportserver/")
//@ReportsCrashes(formKey = "", formUri = "http://myreleasecrashreportserver/")
public class MyApplication extends Application { ... }
```

Dependent on the build type, ACRA should report to different servers.

```
public class Configuration {
    public static final String APPLICATION_BASE_URL = "https://mydebugendpoint/api/rest";
    // public static final String APPLICATION_BASE_URL = "https://myreleaseendpoint/api/rest";

    public static final String GA_TRACKING_ID = "UA-XXXXXXXX-Y"; // debug Analytics
    // public static final String GA_TRACKING_ID = "UA-ZZZZZZZZ-Y"; // release Analytics
}
```

Dependent on the build type my API endpoint and my analytics account differ.

And it's very annoying and there are potential bugs when I have to remind to do theese changes manually before every build.

So how can I automate this in Android Studio and/or Gradle?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found the solution. It is described in [Android Docs](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Sourcesets-and-Dependencies).

I have to create additional folders named debug and release and whatever buildvariant I'd like and put the sourcefiles dependent on that variant there.

Comment: Link-only answers can become invalid if the link gets broken. It is better to explain how the link worked for you. Your research and reading all of that will help others.

Comment: so can i have a same anmed java class in debug release and stagging build types ? currently AS is giving me duplication error